# Not able to ssh from outside to home ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, router

I have netgear router. Initially I had forwarded all tcp ports to internal server 192.168.0.100 centos

I was able to ssh into that using my `ssh user@publicip`.

now I have installed Ubuntu trusty with `IP 192.168.0.32` and forwarded all ports on router to that IP.

But I am not able to ssh from outside. I get error `ssh: connect to host 12.15.14.44 port 22: Connection timed out.`

I am able to ssh within internal network.

I have no `firewall` and no `selinux` enable in Ubuntu.

What else can I check?

Its not only ssh but port 80 is also not accessible

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38758           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31944/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7343/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      692/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21368/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7911/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7605/master
tcp6       0      0 :::47082                :::*                    LISTEN      31944/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      692/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      20447/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      21368/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      7605/master
```

Comment: Have you verified it is listening with netstat?

Comment: @MaQleod i have added netstat ouput

Comment: If it works internally on the network, then a netstat is not needed. An online port checker tool shows port 22 is closed on your external IP: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ - Double check your port forwarding

Comment: @Tillman32 yes my port 80 is also coming as closed. how can i open it

Comment: @user1721949 Well that netstat shows both port 80 and 22 are listening on your server ( meaning the services are up ) so your router needs to be forwarding those ports to your ubuntu servers IP. That's the problem, something in your forwarding.

Comment: @Tillman32 this is my router log `Fri, 2014-03-14 01:32:07 - TCP Packet - Source:22.14.146.43,54437 Destination:12.14.19.44,22 - [Any(TCP) rule match]` it is forwarding to client. how can i check if server is receving some thing

Comment: You can use tcpdump to watch on a specific port if you want to verify traffic coming in to an interface.

Comment: I don't see apache2 listening on 80 on ipv4, it is only on ipv6, but sshd is listening on both.

Comment: @MaQleod how can i fix that. also i see that i had same netstat ouput in other centos box which si working fine

Comment: Not sure about apache2, i'm not that familiar with the config for it. The next step for ssh would be to run tcpdump -i <iface_name> port 22 on the box and then attempt a connection. The traffic (or lack thereof) should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @user1721949 To clarify, is the following the case? 1) You _can_ ssh to the _private_ IP of the server from _within_ your network; 2) You _can_ ssh to the _public_ IP of your home internet connection from _within_ your network; 3) You _cannot_ ssh to the _public_ IP of your home internet connection from _outside_ your network

Comment: @cpast yes u r right. i can not ssh to ubuntu but i can to centos

Answer (score 0):

- first use tcpdump to make sure that ubuntu doesnt get the traffic, then if not..
- ..change IP of the centos from 192.168.0.100 to another free IP, 192.168.0.2xx,
- add an alias to ubuntu, so that is has 192.168.0.32 AND 192.168.0.100 in the same time and
- try sshing from outside. if it works then the problem with the netgear is that it still forwards connections to the old IP